# Option value not displaying if the value is 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-jtable

I have jquery jtable  that has dynamic options.It works fine.If i select 0 from the drop down then it won't display the table.when load the table for the first time it works fine.But when i update[image] the options the value 0 is not displaying.

If i  have any other number other than 0 then it will display.The third row is  an example.I select 0 from the drop down it updates the database correctly but won't show on the table.Does any body know why is it happening.I tried loading the table but still its not working.

The following is the code .

```
  $('#cribList').jtable({
                    sorting: true,
                    defaultSorting: 'Number ASC',
                    selecting: true, //Enable selecting
                    multiselect: true, //Allow multiple selecting
                    selectingCheckboxes: true, //Show checkboxes on first column
                    actions: {
                        listAction: 'Rooms.aspx/LoadRoom?database=<%= Request["database"].ToString() %>',
                        deleteAction: 'Rooms.aspx/DeleteRoom?database=<%= Request["database"].ToString() %>',
                        updateAction:  'Rooms.aspx/UpdateRoom?database=<%= Request["database"].ToString() %>',
                        createAction: 'Rooms.aspx/CreateRoom?database=<%= Request["database"].ToString() %>'
                    },

     TypeID: {
              title: 'Type',
              width: '30%',
              inputClass: 'validate[required]',
              options: <%= DisplayRoomOptions() %>
              },

        Stacks:{
                     title:  'Stacks',
                     width: '30%',
                     dependsOn:'TypeID',
                     listClass: 'centerCol',
                     options: function (data)
                         {
                            if (data.source  == 'list')
                             {
                             return <%=appdomain%> +'/Rooms.aspx/GetRoomOptions?TypeID=0';
                             }
                            return  <%=appdomain%> +'/Rooms.aspx/GetRoomOptions?TypeID='+data.dependedValues.TypeID;
                        }   


Code behind

      [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
     public static object GetRoomOptions(int TypeID)
            {

                try
                {
                    int[] configRooms = new int[6]; ;

                    if (TypeID == 2)
                       configRooms = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
                    else if ((TypeID == 3) || (TypeID == 4))
                        configRooms = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
                    else if (TypeID == 1)
                        configRooms = new int[] { 0 };
                    else
                       configRooms = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
                    return new { Result = "OK", Options = configRooms };

                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return new { Result = "ERROR", Message = ex.Message };
                }

            }
```

Update code

---

```
 [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]

 public static object UpdateRoom(GuardRoomData.Room.record)
    {
        try
        {
            record.Save(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
            return new { Result = "OK" };
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            GuardRoomData.Log.WriteError("Save Room (user '" + HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name + "'): " + ex.ToString());
            return new { Result = "ERROR", Message = "Save Room failed: " + ex.Message };
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're going to need to share the relevant code if you want any answers. Try to only include the bits of code to reproduce your problem rather than the whole project.

Comment: Share your code ... since this only seems t happen with 0, then probably there is an if statement that evaluate to false... just a guess